# Where does an empty return statement lead in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, return

For the code below, both WriteLine results outputs are 30.

I do not know why the second result is 30 too.

I think if the value is `-1`, then the program runs out of the curly brace `{ return; }`, and moves to the next line after `{}`.

Is it correct?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person pp = new Person();
        pp.Age = 30;
        // Output is 30
        Console.WriteLine("the age is {0}", pp.Age);
        pp.Age = -1;
        // Output is 30 again
        Console.WriteLine("the age is {0}", pp.Age);

    }
}

class Person
{
    private int age;
    public int Age
{
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            // An empty return statement
            return; 
        }

        // if the value is -1, does it go through this line?
        this.age = value; 

    }
    get
    {
        return this.age;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You don't return a set.  You Throw an exception if the value is not appropriate.

Comment: The return will stop setting pp.Age to -1 and the next statement (2nd console writeline) will be executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` keyword returns control out of the function (regardless of how many nested scopes you are in). This "bail-out" approach is one reason why early returns are considered bad practice. So basically, your program flows like this:

1. Call setter with 30
2. value > 0, skip what is in {}
3. Set backing field to 30
4. Print property (still 30)
5. Call setter with -1
6. value < 0, execute what is in {}
7. Return, function execution stops and returns to the caller
8. Print property (still 30 since nothing got set)

If you are doing validation in your setter, throwing an exception is a much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The return statement exits the property setter before setting the age value.  Nothing is returned, as a setter is like a void method.  It looks like you don't want to set an age less than 0, which makes sense.

Some apps decide to throw an `ArgumentException` in cases like this rather than silently failing.

Answer (score 1):

Your setter is just returning if the value is less than 0 so you never set the age when you attempt to set it as -1. The setter should be:

```
public int Age {
    set { age = value; }
}
```

Unless you don't want to set age if it's less than 0 you would want to throw an exception:

```
public int Age {
    set {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        age = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` will cause a method to immediately exit a method, not merely leave a scope in `{ }`.

There are some cases you want to exit a scope, but not a method. That is done with `break`, but works in loops.

```
for (;;)
  if (condition)
    break; // breaks out of the loop
```

I think what you are trying to do is protect age from negative values. I recommend using exceptions.

```
public int Age
{
  set
  {
    if (value < 0)
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Age cannot be negative");
    age = value;
  }
  get
  {
    return age;
  }
}
```